# How to tunnel remote UNIX socket on Windows machine

Tags: windows, sockets, ssh, putty, tunnel

On remote UNIX machine I have running MySQL on UNIX socket and I want to have a connection to this MySQL on my local Windows machine.

Previously I used next command that works on my Mac:

```
ssh -nNT -L 127.0.0.1:3307:<remote_socket_path> <remote_user>@<remote_ip> -p <remote_port>
```

On Windows I tried various tools like Plink and had no success, all of those tools expects *host:port* setup and doesn't recognize a socket path.

So what am I doing wrong and how I can tunnel remote socket like I'm doing it on Mac using SSH command?

Comment: FYI, forwarding unix domain sockets isn't a standard SSH protocol feature; it's an OpenSSH extension.

Comment: OpenSSH is now part of Windows, I believe (read it at https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/). Can someone with access to a Windows box confirm whether it can forward to a UNIX socket path on the remote?

Comment: @Amir, it works. I can forward /var/run/docker.sock to Windows host via OpenSSH implementation of ssh client. Note, putty version of cli still doesn't support unix socket forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now ships a version of OpenSSH, which is the same implementation that is commonly found in desktop and server Linux and other UNIX installations, as part of Windows. As of [the April 2018 Update](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/) of Windows 10, the same command that had worked on the Mac would work in a Windows CMD or Powershell:

```
ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:3307:<remote_socket_path> -p <remote_port> <remote_user>@<remote_ip>
```

Plink, and possibly Putty for some use cases, are no longer necessary.